# Java, Maven, JSP, JPA - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, jpa

I'm making a challenge for a job application. Essentially i need to make a CRUD using Java, Maven, JSP and JPA with Hibernate. Every time that i try to get the resultList of my consult in the Database this error returns. The "id" is defined as int in the DB.

```
"ago 27, 2019 9:45:18 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/home.xhtml]
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)[...]"
```

```
"ago 27, 2019 9:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/desafiosefaz] threw exception [For input string: "id"] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)[...]"
```

I've tried to change the type of id in the User class by using the long type, but the error still happens, i really don't know what is happening.

Thats the User

```
package desafiosefaz.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="usuarios")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        @Column
        private String login;
        @Column
        private String nome;
        @Column
        private String email;
        @Column 
        private String senha;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }
        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }
        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getSenha() {
            return senha;
        }
        public void setSenha(String senha) {
            this.senha = senha;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", login=" + login + ", email=" + email + "]";
        }


}
```

Thats my DAO

```
public List<User> listarUsuarios() {
        List<User> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
        Query q = entity.createQuery("SELECT id, nome, login, email FROM User ORDER BY nome DESC");
        listaUsuarios = q.getResultList();
        return listaUsuarios;
    }
```

Thats the Bean

```
public List<User> listarUsuarios() {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        return userDAO.listarUsuarios();
    }
```

Thats the xhtml

```
<h:dataTable value="#{userBean.listarUsuarios()}" var="usuario" border="1">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                <h:outputText type="int" value="#{usuario.id}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{usuario.nome}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Login</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{usuario.login}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

I expected that the ID would just pop in the table like it usually do.

Comment: a) what does the `User` bean looks like? b) How is `id` defined in the DB ?

Comment: The User looks like this ``` @Entity
 @Table(name="usuarios")
 public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id; ``` and the "id" is defined as int in the DB.

Comment: Just a short guess: It has nothing to do with JPA, but with some JSF binding. Would be good to add more of the stacktrace. Which JSF version are you using, I've never seen the `type` attribute for `h:outputText`? And please read the help before posting additional information - you know that you can edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

another scenario is there , when you submit your from/data this time in background its convert data in String so convert  id - String to int before execution of query